# Youtube v3/videos API returns wrong number of commetns

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

After deleating comment on video **commentCount** field is not updated. For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoDoe6rK2a0) was with 1 comment but after I deleted it the API continues to return **1** as count of comments.

Api call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
part: id,statistics
id: CoDoe6rK2a0
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/j7tFb2p4vQHvGO4jdm1Qvuz01zo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/SP5Xvf63pkDP90houUhxO95qiKM\"",
   "id": "CoDoe6rK2a0",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "14",
    "likeCount": "0",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "1"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But as you can see in Youtube the list of comments is empty and the response of v3/comments endpoint is empty *items* array also.

Comment: I would wait and check again periodically. Maybe the value you get is cached by YT and needs some time until it is updated.

Comment: Yes, it's already updated - more than 24 later.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Videos.list Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) works as expected and updates fast.

```
part: statistics
videoId: MY_VIDEO_ID
```

When I deleted one of the comments and ran the Try-it, it updated immediately. 
Make sure you're internet connection is working fine too.

Comment: There is no problem with my internet connection. But commentCount is still wrong for an hours after deleting some comment. I don't think this is normal behavior.

Comment: It's deleted via Youtbue UI by account owner.